# Zend application and click fraud detections

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, session

Hi i have an zend application which generate an ads based content, when a user signup he can start sharing the ads by just copy paste the URL in fb,tw or g+ . The problems is i had detected a several clicks from the same ip address from users...some goes 200 clicks within few seconds.What is best way to prevent multiple clicks from a similar ip address? need an idea in code form..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Due to network setup, one company with 1,000 employees could all have the same IP address.  If 200 of them all get an E-mail memo to click something, it could appear as if the same IP has clicked a link 200 times in a few seconds.  (My Company does this.  Though, we don't have 1,000 office employees.)  So you have to account for this if you want each of those people to be counted if they're individuals.

(1) One thing to do is to set a cookie on the first click and then ignore further clicks if they have that cookie.  This will help with the above as it will be per PC.  Since this scenario, you're not dealing with people likely trying to game the system, they will likely have Cookies enabled.

(2) Second thing to do is to store the IP address.  You can allow "x" number of clicks in a given timeframe and then start rejecting clicks from that IP address after that time, until "Y" amount of time has passed.  This will help with those trying to game the system and who will more likely not have cookies enabled due #1 above.

You could store these in a database with a timestamp and then just apply some business logic on the timestamp for what you want to accept in terms of "clicks per second per IP".

Now, this is all a fairly "uncomplicated" way of trying to prevent click fraud.  Search Engines and other business who sell ads employ a much more complicated logic for avoiding click fraud.  They will also look at metrics such as the user agent string, etc.

I hope that helps!

Cheers!